# Singleton pattern with ini4j

Tags: java, singleton, inputstream, fileinputstream

Original issue: The program was reading the inputs of the old config file (.ini)

New issue: After attempting a singleton pattern with the stream/ini, I am unable to write to file anymore. Its throwing a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Is there anyway I can modify my Configuration class to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Configuration class:

```
import org.ini4j.Wini;
import java.io.*;

//http://www.javenue.info/post/40

public class Configuration {
    private static Configuration _instance = null;

    private Wini ini = null;
    FileInputStream stream;

    private Configuration() {
        ini= new Wini();
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(Constants.PATH);
            ini.load(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
        }
    }

    public synchronized static Configuration getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new Configuration();
        return _instance;
    }

    public String getConfig(String xSectionName, String xFieldValue){

        String readValue = null;

        if (ini.get(xSectionName, xFieldValue) != null) {
            readValue = ini.get(xSectionName, xFieldValue);
        } else {
            // TODO: What should happen
        }
        return readValue;
    }

    public void setConfig(String xSectionName, String xFieldValue, String xValue){

        System.out.println("Section: " + xSectionName);
        System.out.println("Field:   " + xFieldValue);
        System.out.println("Value:   " + xValue + "\n\n");

        try {
            ini.put(xSectionName, xFieldValue, xValue);
            ini.store();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println(xValue + " could not be stored.");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> Section: drift
>
> Field:   mu
>
> Value:   5
>
> 5 could not be stored.
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException     at org.ini4j.Ini.store(Ini.java:126)
>     at
>   application.prototypes.Configuration.setConfig(Configuration.java:72)
>     at application.prototypes.UserInputs.lambda$0(UserInputs.java:92)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:148)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:246)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Resolution to New Issue: See answer below.

Resolution to Original Issue:

I was dynamically loading a class with the Java-Runtime-Compiler library. After some research, I read that a ClassLoader can only have one instance of a particular class. So, the solution is to create a new instance of a ClassLoader in the .loadFromJava() method and boom problem solved.

Here is a bit of code.

```
import net.openhft.compiler.CompilerUtils;

...

ClassLoader classloader = new ClassLoader() {
        };

Class aClass = CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava(classloader, className, javaCode);

Callable<Object[]> caller = (Callable<Object[]>) aClass.newInstance();

Object[] obj = (Object[]) caller.call();

...
```

The dynamic class implements Callable and returns the object - so one can retrieve whatever its created in there.

Comment: Is `System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");` executed at runtime ?

Comment: For the singleton, you can do simpler and without explicit synchronization with Bill Pugh's singleton implementation

Comment: @davidxxx it is printing " ... could not be stored."

Comment: Ok and can you post the stacktrace related to this exception ?

Comment: I think the problem is the stream - when it tries to write then it does not have access anymore. I am hoping there is a way to overcome this.

Comment: I have seen. Thank you. I am writing to you a complete response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just looked in the source code.
The problem is that `void load(InputStream input)` in `Wini` class should be avoided to load the ini file if you want to use the same `Wini` instance to invoke the `store()` method. 

Why ?
Because the `store()` method expects to have a existing file field in the instance of the current `Wini` but it cannot find it as you have loaded the ini from a stream and not a file.

So you should load the ini file by using the `Wini` constructor. The constructor taking as parameter a `File` and it also sets the field inside the instance  additionally to load the ini content.

Look at this :

```
public Wini(File input) throws IOException, InvalidFileFormatException{
        this();
        setFile(input);
        load();
}
```

So replace :

```
 private Configuration() {
        ini = new Wini();
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(Constants.PATH);
            ini.load(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
        }
    }
```

by this :

```
private Configuration()  {
    try {
        ini= new Wini(new File(Constants.PATH));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception during init of Configuration",e);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the full class using logging to log exception and which use a lazy singleton implementation without using any explicit synchronization as `synchronized`:

```
public class Configuration {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class)//

    private static class HolderLazySingleton {
        private static Configuration instance = new Configuration();
    }

    private Wini ini = null;

    private Configuration() {    
        try {
            ini = new Wini(new File(Constants.PATH));    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception during init of Configuration",e);
        }
    }

    public static Configuration getInstance() {
        return HolderLazySingleton.instance;
    }

    public String getConfig(String xSectionName, String xFieldValue) {

        String readValue = null;

        if (ini.get(xSectionName, xFieldValue) != null) {
            readValue = ini.get(xSectionName, xFieldValue);
        } else {
            // TODO: What should happen
        }
        return readValue;
    }

    public void setConfig(String xSectionName, String xFieldValue, String xValue) {

        System.out.println("Section: " + xSectionName);
        System.out.println("Field:   " + xFieldValue);
        System.out.println("Value:   " + xValue + "\n\n");

        try {
            ini.put(xSectionName, xFieldValue, xValue);
            ini.store();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            LOGGER.error(xValue + " could not be stored.", e1);         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the "write" problem and made it so much easier to troubleshoot the original problem. I added an explanation in the description if you are curious. Thanks again - and happy holidays.

Comment: Excellent news. I have seen the solution for the original problem : interesting. You are welcome. Happy holidays for you too :)